# Can I put CMakeLists.txt(s) in a separate folder?

Tags: cmake

I know people typically organize files for a project like or similar to this:

```
project_root
    CMakeLists.txt
    main
        CMakeLists.txt
        inc
            main.h
        src
            main.cpp
    lib0
        CMakeLists.txt
        inc
            lib0.h
        src
            lib0.cpp
    ...
```

But I would like to make a project more friendly and neat for both CMake and Visual Studio considering cross platform, so ideally I want it to be organized like the following

```
project_root
    build
        cmake
           CMakeLists.txt       //will include _main.txt and _lib0.txt
           CMakeLists_main.txt  //for main  
           CMakeLists_lib0.txt  //for lib0
        vs2017
           xxx.sln
           xxx_main.vcxproj
           xxx_lib0.vcxproj
    main
        inc
            main.h
        src
            main.cpp
    lib0
        inc
            lib0.h
        src
            lib0.cpp
    ...
```

I know it's ok for VS2017, but I am not even sure whether it's doable for CMake or not, I did a lot of search online but couldn't figure it out, any help from you will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You use CMake so your project will be cross-platform, as it support various generators including Visual Studio. After you have a project for CMake, you just generate the Visual Studio solution out of that CMake project.

Comment: I know CMake can generate VS .sln/.prj files, the whole point is to separate build configuration files from .h/.cpp files to make the inc/src folder more neat.

Comment: It seems you want to keep both CMakeLists and .sln file in you repository. Given this is cross-platform, how do you expect Linux users to update .sln file when they add any .cpp file? Which one should be used for testing and what will happen once they differ? I guess you have not found anything about such approach, since it is counter-CMake way and none has done it yet. Technically, `include` command can load any file you specify it, so you can have main CMakeLists.txt call `include(CMakeLists_main.txt)`. But generally, I don't recommend it, as you lose directories scoping.

Comment: I won't say it 's better for VS users too since CMake has a builtin support in VS2017 and Microsoft tend to follow the CMake-way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, after all the try-out, I realized it doesn't worth it because CMake out-of-directory can cause a lot of compatibility issues for different IDEs, I would rather simply follow the CMake convention to put CMakeLists.txt in the root folder and each sub-folder of source code.

Comment: Have you tried a suggestion at https://discourse.cmake.org/t/how-to-explicitly-specify-cmake-to-process-a-different-txt-file/938/2?